# Does there exist a continuous bijection from $(-1,1) \to (-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Does there exist a continuous bijection from $(-1,1) \to (-1,1]$?

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous bijection from $(-1,1) \to (-1,1]$.Then $f^{-1}(1)=a$ where $a\in (-1,1)$.

Since restriction of a continuous map is continuous so $f|_{(-1,a)\cap (a,1)}$ is  a continuous map its image is $(-1,1)$.

But it is not giving anything.Please give some hints.I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Pick $b<a<c$, then $f(b)<1$ and $f(c)<1$. Pick $t$ between $\max(f(b),f(c))$ and $1$, then, by the IVT, there exists $x$ in $(b,a)$ and $y$ in $(a,c)$ such that $f(x)=t$ and $f(y)=t$. Oops, $f(x)=f(y)$ but $x\ne y$...

Comment: @Did isn't this an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Where do these $a,b,c $ lie

Comment: What? $a$ is in your post, $b$ and $c$ are anything in $(-1,a)$ and in $(a,1)$ respectively. As explained in my first comment.

Comment: Okay ;I did not understand you were using my notation;Thank you

Comment: There's surely a slick topological proof of this but I can't think of it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more "topological" version of Did's comment, suppose $f(a) = 1$ and fix any $0 < c < a < d < 1$.  Then $[c,d]$ is a compact interval, so its image is another compact interval $[u,1]$, and since $f$ is a continuous bijection on the compact set $[c,d]$, it is a homeomorphism.  This would imply that $f$ also gives a homeomorphism from $[c,a) \cup (a,d]$ to $[u,1)$, which is absurd since the latter is connected and the former is not.